# SQL custom function to calculate price of product after discount applied to it

Tags: sql

I need help to write a Custom function in order to calculate Price of Product post the discount is applied.

I am fresh to SQL, hence went through few articles.

Came up with Scalar function and in order to execute the above result wrote the below code.

But no Success :(

```
CREATE FUNCTION CalcPrice
(
@PriceOrg decimal(10,2),
@PrdPrice decimal(10,2)
)
RETURNS decimal (10, 2)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE SELECT(@PriceOrg - @PrdPrice)
END
```

Save the above function and call the function as below

```
SELECT dbo.CalcPrice();
```

But nothing works for me.

Below Image for the Product table

[image: Products Table]

Comment: First of all, could you please let us know what DBMS are you using? then, do you actually need  a function ?  this can be done with a simple select statement like Select Prodid, ProdName, PriceOrg - PrdPrice as CalPrice from Product

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a SELECT in such function.

So try this

```
CREATE FUNCTION CalcPrice (
 @OrgPrice decimal(10,2),
 @PrdPrice decimal(10,2)
)
RETURNS decimal(10,2)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Result decimal(10,2);
  SET @Result = @OrgPrice - @PrdPrice;
  RETURN @Result;
END;
```

```
SELECT *
, dbo.CalcPrice(PriceOrg, PrdPrice) AS Price
FROM Product
```

Comment: Checking it now

Comment: Amazing , it works nice and shows the desired results for me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm guessing you're just learning atm. Because like was said in comments, this logic is so simple that you really don't need a UDF for it.  `(OrgPrice - PrdPrice) as Price`

Comment: Thats true Sir. Can you please suggest on this to me? stored procedure for updating cart, (let’s assume a scenario – user added a product in 
cart and but after that Product owner decided to increase/decrease price of that product) then
these price change need to be reflected in cart’s product

Comment: Not sure what too suggest. Just random wisdom idiom : "Practice Makes Perfect" .

Comment: Thank you Sir! Will give it a try not to forget logic :P